# Aligning definition of a function that maps into a function space

Tags: math-mode, spacing, align

I'm writing a proof that the dual of l^p is l^q, and in that process, I define a function from l^q to (l^p)*. My current function definition looks like this:

```
\begin{align*}
  \varphi:\ell^q\longrightarrow (\ell^p)^*& \\
  \mathbf{x}\longmapsto f_{\mathbf{x}}:&\ell^p \longrightarrow\mathbb{C} \\
  &\mathbf{y}\longmapsto\sum_{k=1}^\infty x_k y_k
\end{align*}
```

This produces the following result:

[image: Typeset isomorphism]

I would like to align the definition so that the arrows are directly above each other. I have tried to do this using alignment characters in the following manner:

```
\begin{align*}
  \varphi:\ell^q&\longrightarrow& (\ell^p)^*& \\
  \mathbf{x}&\longmapsto& f_{\mathbf{x}}:\ell^p &\longrightarrow&\mathbb{C} \\
  &&\mathbf{y}&\longmapsto&\sum_{k=1}^\infty x_k y_k
\end{align*}
```

This gives the desired alignment, but mucks up the spacing:
[image]

I wonder if there's a way to typeset this so that the arrows are aligned, but no additional spacing is produced.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `alignat*`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
  \begin{alignat*}{2}
  \varphi:\ell^q&\longrightarrow& (\ell^p)^* \\
  \mathbf{x}&\longmapsto& f_{\mathbf{x}}:\ell^p &\longrightarrow\mathbb{C} \\
  &&\mathbf{y}&\longmapsto\sum_{k=1}^\infty x_k y_k
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is very simple and exactly what I needed

Answer (score 3):

You can do that either with `alignat*{2}` or with an `aligned` environment nested in `align*`. I added a pair of parentheses for the definition of the image-function:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier, heuristica}

\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
  \varphi:\ell^q& ―――→ \bigl(\ell^p\big)^*\\
  \mathbf{x}&\longmapsto \big(f_{\mathbf{x}}: ℓ ^p & ―――→ {}& \mathbb{C} \\[-1ex]
  && \mathllap{\mathbf{y}}\longmapsto & \medop∑_{\mathclap{k=1}}^∞ x_k y_k\big)
\end{alignat*}

\begin{align*}
  \varphi:\ell^q& ―――→ \bigl(\ell^p\big)^* \\
  \mathbf{x}&\longmapsto\!\begin{aligned}[t]\big(f_{\mathbf{x}}:\ell^p & ―――→ \mathbb{C} \\[-1ex]
   \mathbf{y}& \longmapsto \medop∑_{\mathclap{k=1}}^∞ x_k y_k\big)
\end{aligned}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Some manual work, but one can precisely align the elements. Please observe `\colon`'s in place of `:`'s.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{r@{\;}c@{\;}l@{\;}c@{\;}l}
  \varphi\colon\ell^q&\longrightarrow& (\ell^p)^*&& \\[6pt]
  \mathbf{x}&\longmapsto& f_{\mathbf{x}}\colon\ell^p &\longrightarrow&\mathbb{C} \\[3pt]
 & &\multicolumn{1}{r}{\mathbf{y}}&\longmapsto&\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^\infty x_k y_k
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]